# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Creating the web driver failed with the message "End of Central Directory record could not be found."

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to run the test cases using Selenium and I keep getting this error
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Creating the web driver failed with the message "End of Central Directory record could not be found.". This can mean that there is a leftover web driver process that you have to kill manually. Full exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.

It was working fine earlier. I'm facing this issue from last 4 or 5 hour without making any chgange.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.